# Y86 assembly global variables

Tags: assembly, y86

I am struggling to get global variables to work correctly for my Y86 assignment.  Unfortunately the only examples we were provided with are in IA-32 assembly.  I have searched for the last few hours but to no avail. This is very basic I know but I am a complete novice at Y86.

I am "declaring" my variables as follows

```
.align 4
x: .long 1
y: .long 4
```

When I use them in an operation such as `irmovl x, %edx` I see the value 380 is assigned to the edx register instead of the value 4.  I think what is happening is that I am assigned the memory location to the register instead of the value.  What would be the correct syntax to set the value of the global variable to the register?

I have tried using mrmovl instead but am unsure of the syntax for mrmovl with a global variable.

mrmovl x, %edx give me the error "x is not a number"

Answer (score 1):

`irmovl` as the name says is **i**mmediate to **r**egister.
You want `mrmovl` as that is **m**emory to **r**egister.

As for the syntax, since y86 does support displacement, I would expect `mrmovl x, %edx` to work. You say it doesn't, as a workaround you could use 2 instructions:

```
irmovl x, %edx     # load address
mrmovl (%edx), %edx # fetch value
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I have tried this but if I use mrmovl x, %edx I get the error x is not a number.  Unfortunately I have no good examples of syntax available.  What would the syntax be for mrmovl using  the global x?

Comment: Jester, `irmovl $x, %edx     # load address` should be `irmovl x, %edx     # load address`. Your description is correct, but a typo in the code. I have corrected your code.

Comment: @MichaelPetch thanks, I assumed it copied at&t syntax, but apparently not that much.